# SO Edit timing problem

Tags: feature-request

This is a problem I have noted several times. I am editing a post and when I submit it, it is edited by someone else and will result in rejection. I have seen that sometimes it shows a warning saying that someone has already edited the post. But as I said, **sometimes**. Not most of the times.

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163319/cancel-or-update-edit-suggestion-when-out-of-sync) a while ago when I had the same issue...

Comment: The warning is not "live", I think there's AJAX polling the server once every 30-60 seconds so if other edit was submitted before that it won't show the warning..

Comment: Not found on searching. And  I wonder still it does not have any answer!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd May be,but as a result say if i got the same issue in mre than 10 times a day, I will be suspended from edit while I am not done anything suspicious. Approvers should check this too.

Comment: @ACB, I doubt if we can do anything about this. For something like SO where there is a huge traffic, these kind of issues tend to happen.

Comment: @ACB from quick look many of your edits are rejected by users who click Improve and reject your edit on purpose as being not useful. As for the auto reject due to conflicting edit I agree it's an issue but simply don't edit so fast, give it some minutes first.